# How to define a json schema for the following json?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json file which has the following contents. I am not sure on how to specify the json schema for it. May someone please guide me on how to do it. I have never worked with it before and would appreciate any help.

```
json_temp = {          
                'taskid': '10',
                'taskstatus': 'in progress',

                'Kitchen': 
                {                    
                    'Stove':{
                                'LED1':
                                {
                                'taskid': '11',
                                'taskstatus':'running'
                                },

                                'LED2':
                                {
                                    'taskid': '12',
                                    'taskstatus':'off',
                                    'LEDSub':
                                    { 
                                       'taskid': '13',
                                       'taskstatus':'stable',
                                       'LEDSub2':
                                        {
                                           'taskid': '14',
                                           'taskstatus':'burnt'
                                        }
                                    }
                                },

                                'LED3':
                                {
                                'taskid': '15',
                                'taskstatus':'new'
                                } 
                           },
                  //other nested layers
               }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is no one schema that you can derive given a single example. The schema *defines* which JSON values are valid and which aren't. Start simple: define *a* schema, then figure out why it doesn't accept your example and modify it. Once you have a schema that accepts your example, try it against *different* examples and see what needs to be adjusted.

Comment: As a first step, I would put the single LED1...LEDn objects as array items. Like: LEDS: [ { }, { }, ... ]

Comment: @chepner I am not sure on how to start my schema. My json file could have many nested layers and I can't hardcode a specific layout, right? May you please guide me with a sample json schema?

Comment: You can use references to make a recursive structure. You can also use `patternProperties` for when you want to have properties that match a regex as opposed to being specific keys. Sorry I can't be of further help today. If you're still stuck by Tuesday, make a comment here again, or ask in the JSON Schema slack.

Comment: @Relequestual I am still unable to find a solution to this. I would require more help. I cant find the link to the Json schema slack?